# RTSP stream on native iphone app/website

Tags: iphone, mobile, embed, quicktime, rtsp

Making a native website iPhone app (converting a website to an iphone app) I want to stream this rtsp link: rtsp://67.85.223.199:110/cgi-bin/rtspStream/1 (there is no file extension I don't know why) if you enter that as a url on quick time it works. I can't embed it correctly for the iphone for it to work. I figure if I can stream it to a browser without active x it should be compatible for the iPhone. Tried a bunch of way to do this, hoping someone out there as the answer :) 
-Mike

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your URL, you are streaming with an IP camera. That can easily be restreamed to iPhone, Flash players, Android, anything, really. You may need to make sure your camera can stream H264 and AAC if you want audio. Our company is doing something similar with NetroMedia. http://www.netromedia.com/

Comment: Your answer doesn't give any indication of /how/ one can re-stream to iOS, it basically just states "this is possible with our product". Sorry, it's a no from me.